# How to find the highest number by sorting inside alphanumerical string in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to get the highest number inside of these alphanumerical strings:

```
    [
{
    "LsNr": "L9"        
},
{
    "LsNr": "L99"
},
{
    "LsNr": "L100"
}
    ]
```

However, MongoDB returns `L9` as the highest number in my C# method:

```
        public string MaxLsNr<T>(string cl, string prefix) //collection and prefix 'L'
        {
            string bsonQuery = "{'LsNr': {$regex: '" + prefix + "'}}"; //filter by prefix
            var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bsonQuery);

            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cl);

            //returns `L9` instead of `L100`
            var result = collection.Find(filter).Sort("{LsNr: -1}").Limit(1).ToList();
            //some more code
        }
```

What is the way around this? You don't need to answer C# related. It is alright for me if you explain possible options (without changing the existing key-value pairs) or directly the MongoDB query (preferred).

Comment: @srinivasy Did the query not work as expected?

Comment: yes it is, issue is with your query, please check my answer of how to query for that specific requirement &  as I'm not an expert in `C#`, please convert it to your req. Also I've missed to get highest number - please add `$limit` to my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of MongoDB's string comparison, if I'm not wrong you might be getting this order `"L99" > "L9" > "L100"` , cause it would check letter by letter in a given string, So Since `L` matches in all documents then it would go for next letter that way it will give you above order.

1) In case all of documents has **LsNr** starts with **L** try this :

**Query :**

```
collection.aggregate([
/** $match similar to .find() */
{ $match: { filter } },
/** $addFields to add a new field 'number' which bring number out of 'L9' -> 9 */
{ $addFields: { number: { $toInt: { $substr: ["$LsNr", 1, -1] } } } },
/** sort number & $project to remove newly created field 'number' */
{ $sort: { number: -1 } }, { $project: { number: 0 } }, {$limit: 1}
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/49a-LVTunKa)

2) Else documents has **LsNr** starts with different letters try this :

**Query :**

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { filter } }, // Your filter
    { $addFields: { letter: { $substr: ["$LsNr", 0, 1] }, number: { $toInt: { $substr: ["$LsNr", 1, -1] } } } },
    { $sort: { number: -1 } }, { $sort: { letter: -1 } },
    { $project: { letter: 0, number: 0 } }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/InfqYowhiEO)

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to achieve what is needed - which is kind of similar to `.find()`. As since you're having filter use it in first stage `$match` to make your dataset less for further stages, Anyway please have an index on field `LsNr`.

Comment: Somehow I've overlooked & missed to get highest number !! So all you've to do is to use `$limit` as last stage in first query/scenario, but if you've second scenario - After second `$sort` remove `$project` & add this `{$group : {_id : '$letter', LsNr : {$first: '$LsNr'}}}`...

Comment: I added `$limit: 1` to your solution. The second variant is not (yet) needed but may become interesting in the future. Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sorting strings, the comparison will be based on each letter starting from the left.

**Suggestion**

- get the data from collection based on your filter
- find the max number (without prefix)
- use that max number to get the first record that matches (which always will be the case)

This will only connect to mongoDb once. Since all the data has been retrieved based on your primary filter, this is just data manipulation locally.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Linq;

public string MaxLsNr<T>(string cl, string prefix) //collection and prefix 'L'
{
    string bsonQuery = "{'LsNr': {$regex: '" + prefix + "'}}"; //filter by prefix
    var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bsonQuery);

    var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(cl);

    var data = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

    // Get the max number from the results.
    int max = data.Max(x => int.Parse(x["LsNr"].ToString().Substring(1)));

    // Get the single record based on Prefix and Max number.
    var result = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x["LsNr"].Equals($"{prefix}{max}");

    // other code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the C# suggestion. The prefix is important as I have values like `L99` but also `F99`. I only want to get the max number depending on the prefix. When callling my MaxLsNr-method, the prefix is passed as a second argument (next to the collection).The idea is to get the highest number depending on the prefix, increase it by 1 and then use this number for a new item (insert) in my collection.

Comment: Where does `LsNr` come from? Where is it declared or assigned with a value? What data type is it?

Comment: @timunix Updated the answer to correctly reference the BsonDocument's fields. I was using code that are strongly typed.

Comment: Your solution is working. The only thing missing (I didn't mention that): There are also key value pairs like these: `LsNr`:`L` (no number) or `LsNr`:`null`. How do I skip these dummy values coming from old user input? The error occurs here: `int max = data.Max(x => int.Parse(x["LsNr"].ToString().Substring(1)));` I am pretty sure it is because of these values. The Substring-method cannot handle them.

Comment: Your filter statement takes care of that. When you run the collection.Find(), it only brings you the documents that have that prefix. You can add a statement that checks if data == null or not

Comment: ok, I got it. I will change my regular expression to exclude all `'L'` values without at least one number following.

Comment: Added a check in the code above to cover the scenario where L has no number associated with it. It will default to 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206880/discussion-between-jawad-and-timunix).